# Storage period of logs in flowground

Tags: flowground

Especially in case of errors it makes sense to write the current data into the log, so that the errors are easier to trace.

In a generic logging solution these logs could easily contain personal, identity or otherwise sensitive information.

In [flowground](https://flowground.net/en), How long are these logs stored? and should i be concerned about the sensitivity of the data that is logged?

Comment: Did you intend for this to be a comment or answer to someone else's question?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please read https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: Tried to interpret OPs intent and express in an easier way to understand

Comment: @ChrisSchaller Thanks for the rewrite. That's what I wanted to know.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Currently flowground uses a maximum disk-space oriented approach to limit the maximum number of logs to be stored.

We currently plan to change that to a time-based approach, something between 3 to 5 days maximum.

Do you have a preference concerning the maximum number of days @Stephan Häußler?

Comment: On our own servers such data is always kept for 7 days. Therefore this interval would be perfect for consistency. If 5 days is the absolute maximum, we can also work with it.